# AngularJS filter results with GET form and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, forms, get

My question is almost the same as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493453/process-form-and-url-with-get-using-jquery-ajax) except I am trying to do this with AngularJS not in jQuery. It would be possible to do this in AngularJS, but it doesn't really feel like the angular way of doing things.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?